# Multiple memory transfers Python Script using Gdal (gdalwarp) w/ GPU on JPEG2000 Datasources

Tags: python, gdal, jpeg-2000

I'm looking at writing a python script that will open a jpeg2000 datasource and decompress it on the GPU, then warp that data using gdalwarp with opencl (also on the GPU)
My question is, will the dataset be copied to ram from the video memory after it's opened, then back to the GPU for the warping, then back to the RAM? or will the data stay in the GPU memory between opening being that both operations happen on the gpu?

If gdal does this in the more efficient way, then I'll be wanting to buy a license or Kakadu jpeg2000 driver but I don't want to fork up the money for it unless there is a good indicator that this is going to work as expected.

Comment: I think that's a little deeper than most python programmers go and also has nothing to do with GIS. I think this question would be better asked on https://stackoverflow.com/ - if you *really* want to speed up the process don't use python, write your code in C++ which will let you *really* control your memory management. Do you really need to purchase a license for JP2KAK for decompression? the lib is available freely for *read only access*.

Comment: I'm using Gdal to do this and is using georeferenced raster datasets.
I wasn't aware that JP2KAK was free for decompression.

Comment: You might be right, I had trouble tracking them down; is there a specific reason why you need Kakadu JP2? There are other options, see the bottom of https://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg2000.html. Are you on Windows? If so the ECW driver is available from https://www.gisinternals.com/ which contains the JP2ECW decompressor.

Comment: After looking a little more, it looks like kakadu is in fact paid only. I want to use Kakadu to decompress on the GPU because it's so much faster. I have essentially endless data that I need to process and am trying to do as much of it on the GPU as possible.
I'm running a linux machine.

Comment: If the compression/decompression of JPEG 2000 is the bottle neck then I believe that something like https://www.fastcompression.com/products/jpeg2000/gpu-jpeg2000.htm would be faster than GDAL with any driver. About how GDAL works internally I would write a mail to the gdal-dev mailing lists. The specialists are all there and they are responsive.